# The POST method always receives NULL when deployed

Tags: c#, rest, post, asp.net-web-api

Our method works fine in dev environment, but when deployed the argument it receives is always null. I'm testing with Postman & SoapUI, with same results.

Example:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/mycontroller/trytypedpostfrombody/")]
    public HttpResponseMessage TryTypedPostFromBody([FromBody]MyClass req)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse($"You have sent with typed POST from body: {(req != null ? JsonConvert.SerializeObject(req) : "<null>")}");
    }
```

Of course, the Postman sends `Content-Type: application/json` and request is a json representation of `MyClass` sent through body.

On dev environment (localhost) it works fine, but when we deploy to client hosting, the service always returns as if agument is `NULL` (i.e. I just switch postman to a different URL, and it returns null instead of what was received). Note that the method *does* get called, it's just the argument that doesn't "survive" the network. If I try similar with passing arguments using `[FromUri]`, it works just fine.

I'd appreciate any ideas as to what to check, because I'm all out of them... (other than switching all methods from `POST` to `GET` /facepalm/)

**Edit**
I've deduced that it's not about POST or GET, it's just the body that gets cut off. So in the meantime we had to change all posts to accept content `[FromUri]` until we get this resolved. Also, there appears to be a Data Power appliance in the middle, but they say they have the same response even if they go directly and not through the URL exposed through DP (which is weird, I would've sworn it's the Data Power configuration issue)

Comment: Just to make sure, are you sure it acts like the req is null instead of returning null through SerializeObject?

Comment: I have faced this issue sometimes where the data which I was sending was not of type MyClass (in your case). May be you are missing something while creating the data object.

Comment: What is your complete local URL? What is your complete client hosting URL? Are **any** routes working on client hosting?

Comment: @StackingForHeap no, `SerializeObject` is called only if not null. @Rakesh It's working when targetting localhost just fine, so I doubt it's that. @mjwills all routes are working - the methods get executed but the values they receive through body are null - other requests that receive through Uri (e.g. GET) work just fine.

Comment: Are you by any chance setting the data type in the (form) with (enctype=xxxx) ? Has this been tested on other servers than (one) client's, maybe there is something weird happening on the server side?

Comment: `the service always returns as if agument is NULL`  What **exact** value is returned from the above function?

Comment: @StackingForHeap - no, no enctype... something weird IS happening on the server side, that's the whole point - but I don't know how can I track it down...

Comment: @mjwills: as I said, the value is null, so you get reply as: "You have sent with typed POST from body: <null>"... does this help?